# How to validate check boxes in jsp and pass values to servlets

Tags: java, jsp, validation, checkbox

In my application the user have to check the check boxes in jsp. This jsp is contructed with data from the db with respect to users request. Now my problem is after the jsp is constructed then how to validate the check box and send only the checked values to jsp. I tried with map and arraylist but not getting the output.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="video_array" value="video1.ogg"> Crickefightsbetweenplayersandaudience </input>

   <source src='videoooggfiles/video1.ogg' type='video/ogg'>
   </source>

   </input>
<div id='media-controls'><button id='play-pause-button' class='play' title='play'      onclick='togglePlayPause();'>Play</button></div>
 </div>

   <input type="checkbox" name="video_array" value="video2.ogg">  ShaneWarnevsMarlonSamulesFight </input>

   <source src='video2.ogg' type='video/ogg'>
   </source>

   </input>
```

Play

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Refine Results</input>
```

Now I have to validate which check boxes are checked and send that values to servlets. The values may be either list or map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in servlet you can get the all selected checkbox values using

```
String [] result = request.getParameterValues("video_array");
```

`getParameterValues()` method returns the String[] array for the input parameter "video_array". It will return null value if you forgot to select checkbox.

Comment: Thanks ;) I got the O/P